# How does pandas calculate skew

Tags: python, pandas

I'm calculating a coskew matrix and wanted to double check my calculation with pandas built in `skew` method.  I could not reconcile how pandas performing the calculation.

define my series as:

```
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series(
    {0: -0.051917457635120283,
     1: -0.070071606515280632,
     2: -0.11204865874074735,
     3: -0.14679988245503134,
     4: -0.088062467095565145,
     5: 0.17579741198527793,
     6: -0.10765856028420773,
     7: -0.11971470229167547,
     8: -0.15169210769159247,
     9: -0.038616800990881606,
     10: 0.16988162977411481,
     11: 0.092999418364443032}
)
```

I compared the following calculations and expected them to be the same.

#### pandas

```
series.skew()

1.1119637586658944
```

#### me

```
(((series - series.mean()) / series.std(ddof=0)) ** 3).mean()

0.967840223081231
```

#### me - take 2

This is significantly different.  I thought it might be [Fisher-Pearson coefficient](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35b.htm).  So I did:

```
n = len(series)
skew = series.sub(series.mean()).div(series.std(ddof=0)).apply(lambda x: x ** 3).mean()
skew * (n * (n - 1)) ** 0.5 / (n - 1)

1.0108761442417222
```

Still off by quite a bit.

#### Question

How does pandas calculate skew?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found [`scipy.stats.skew`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html) with parameter `bias=False` return equal output, so I think in `pandas skew` is `bias=False` by default:

> bias : bool
>
> If False, then the calculations are corrected for statistical bias.

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats.stats as stats

series = pd.Series(
    {0: -0.051917457635120283,
     1: -0.070071606515280632,
     2: -0.11204865874074735,
     3: -0.14679988245503134,
     4: -0.088062467095565145,
     5: 0.17579741198527793,
     6: -0.10765856028420773,
     7: -0.11971470229167547,
     8: -0.15169210769159247,
     9: -0.038616800990881606,
     10: 0.16988162977411481,
     11: 0.092999418364443032}
)

print (series.skew())
1.11196375867

print (stats.skew(series, bias=False))
1.1119637586658944
```

Not sure for 100%, but I think I find it in [code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/103f7d31e1b850e532ed85a4b53ef222d1271c54/pandas/core/generic.py#L5159)

---

EDIT (piRSquared)

From [`scipy` `skew` code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py)

```
if not bias:
    can_correct = (n > 2) & (m2 > 0)
    if can_correct.any():
        m2 = np.extract(can_correct, m2)
        m3 = np.extract(can_correct, m3)
        nval = ma.sqrt((n-1.0)*n)/(n-2.0)*m3/m2**1.5
        np.place(vals, can_correct, nval)
return vals
```

The adjustment was `(n * (n - 1)) ** 0.5 / (n - 2)` and not `(n * (n - 1)) ** 0.5 / (n - 1)`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael.  This now begs the question of how scipy adjusts for bias.  Also, `stats.skew(series)` without the bias parameter matches my calculation.

Comment: Maybe some `scipy` guru know it, me not (unfortunately).

Comment: The function `nanskew` is used by pandas to computed the skewness and is described in [pandas GitHub repo](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a00154dcfe5057cb3fd86653172e74b6893e337d/pandas/core/nanops.py#L540). It's basically the G1 from the Skewness [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Sample_skewness).